# How to solve this problem of dictionaries of Datacamp python course?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

[The question is on the line 9 and the error is on the line 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHYbG.jpg)

I tried to do a auxiliar variable because I thought that .get() function doesn't support multiple indexations.

Comment: Please post your code as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop, you can use the variable year for the key of the outer dictionary because you are iterating with year.  However, for the inner dictionaries, you must explicitly use the string that is the key to that dictionary. Since, I don't have your data, I called it 'names' in the following code, but you can get you actual inner key by what you did in the prior step: print(boy_names[2013].keys()).  Finally, I don't know how the name ranks are arranged in you data, but if it is in a simple list, then the third rank would be the second index:

```
for year in boys_names:
    print(boys_names.get(year).get('names')[2])
```